# Частичное кеширование в Smarty

Tags: smarty

Что-то не пойму как частично кешировать шаблоны в Smarty. Кто может подсказать?

```
{if !$user.id}
                <li><a href="{$home}/login">Вход</a></li>
                <li><a href="{$home}/signup">Регистрация</a></li>
                {else}
                {if $user.level == 100}
                <li><a href="{$home}/admin">Админка</a>
                {/if}   
                <li><a href="{$home}/profile">Кабинет</a></li> 
                <li><a href="{$home}/profile/exit">Выход</a></li>
                {if $setup.mail == 1}<li><a href="{$home}/profile/mail">Сообщения{if $mail} <font color="red">+ {$mail}</font>{/if}</a></li>{/if}   
                {/if}
```

Как кусок этого шаблона не закешировать?

Answer (score 1):

А еще оказывается есть специальный тег - http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.nocache.tpl
Жаль, что нет русской документации по третьей версии смарти.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/ru/caching.tpl

> Вы можете сделать так, чтобы часть
> страницы оставалась динамической, даже
> если страница кэшируется, при помощи
> встроенной функции insert. Например,
> кэшироваться может вся страница, за
> исключением баннера. Используя функцию
> insert для баннера, вы можете
> сохранять этот элемент динамичным,
> внутри кэшированой странички. Смотрите
> документацию по insert для получения
> подробностей и примеров.
>
> Очистить все файлы кэша можно при
> помощи функции clear_all_cache(), а
> конкретный файл кэша (или группу) -
> вызвав clear_cache() функцию.

Задайте вопрос конкретней, пожалуйста. Если Вы хотите, чтобы Вам пересказали статью, то вряд ли кто-то это станет делать не понимая, в чём у Вас возникли проблемы с имеющимися материалами

Comment: Про insert читал, но не понял как его использовать.

Поправил первое сообщение.

Comment: Если кусок шаблона разместить между тегом {block name="head" nocache}тут тот кусок шаблона{/block} то этот кусок не будет закеширован.